# run gradle take a long time and still going

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am currently making a discord bot using Gradle and JDA in Intellij. However, when I tried to run the Gradle - It has been 10 minutes and still going of running the Gradle and it stuck. I tried to clear the cache, close and open the project, and re-build the gradle; I am still stuck at this position

```
12:11:56 PM: Executing task 'run --stacktrace'...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 230 ms

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :processResources
> Task :classes

> Task :run
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Started nijibase with version 1.9.17
STARTING SHARD 0
```

Where did I go wrong? I don't know what else should I put since the stacktrace hasn't showed me where did I go wrong

Comment: I am not sure what your run task is doing but by the looks of the logging, its running your bot. It won't stop until you kill it.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry... Turns out that I misunderstood how the Gradle works. It actually works as it is. This is my first time using Gradle so I still have many things that I don't know about.